# Android app layout components are null when restoring from background after some time

Tags: java, android

The reason for the crash is a `NullPointerException` which is thrown because the fragment's UI Components are null for some reason.

Exception is thrown at this line:

```
private void setGameInfo(Game game) {
    // Stop/hide all ongoing progress bars (loading)
    mSummaryLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

**Exception**: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference`

This is my (very long) fragment code where the progress bar mSummaryLoading can be found

```
public class GameInfoFragment extends Fragment implements GamePageActivity.OnDataLoadedListener {


    public GameInfoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructors
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_info, container, false);
        String dateFormat = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.KEY_PREF_DATE_FORMAT, getString(R.string.default_date_format));
        mDateFormatterGMT = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        mDateFormatterGMT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        mTodayTimeMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        mAlarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // onViewCreated make sure the view is fully created, called after onCreateView
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Summary UI
        mTextSummary = view.findViewById(R.id.summary);
        mReadMore = view.findViewById(R.id.read_more);
        mSummaryLoading = view.findViewById(R.id.summary_loading);
        // Platforms UI
        mPlatformsLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.platforms);
        mPlatformsLayoutExtra = view.findViewById(R.id.platforms_2);
        // Countdown UI
        mHeaderReleasesTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.header_count_down);
        mHeaderReleaseDate = view.findViewById(R.id.header_release_date);
        mCountdownLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.countdown_view);
        mOutNowTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.out_now_txt);
        mDaysTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.days_txt);
        mHoursText = view.findViewById(R.id.hours_txt);
        mMinutesText = view.findViewById(R.id.minutes_txt);
        mSecondsText = view.findViewById(R.id.seconds_txt);
        mCategoryText = view.findViewById(R.id.category_txt);
        mNoteTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.note_txt);
        // Release dates table UI
        mSpinnerRegions = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_regions);
        mNoReleaseDatesTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_releases);
        mReleaseTableLoading = view.findViewById(R.id.releases_loading);
        mTableReleaseDates = view.findViewById(R.id.table_release_dates);
        // Websites (Social link) UI
        mWebsitesList = view.findViewById(R.id.websitesList);
        mNoWebsitesTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_websites_list);
        mSocialLoading = view.findViewById(R.id.social_loading);
        mWebsitesAdapter = new WebsitesAdapter(getContext());
        mWebsitesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        mWebsitesList.setAdapter(mWebsitesAdapter);
        // Start progressbar
        mSummaryLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSocialLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mReleaseTableLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // User region
        String region = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.KEY_PREF_REGION, "north_america");
        mRegion = SharedPrefManager.getRegionToFilter(region);
        // Release social actions
        // The RELEASE DATA OBJECT
        mRelease = ((GamePageActivity)getActivity()).getRelease();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    // When the user signs in in this page [refresh]
                   initHypes(mRelease.getId());
                }
            }
        };
        mReleasesActions = view.findViewById(R.id.release_actions);
        // Favorite
        mAddToFavorite = view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        mAddNote = view.findViewById(R.id.add_note);
        mEditAlarms = view.findViewById(R.id.alarms);
        mShareRelease = view.findViewById(R.id.share);
        mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        // HYPE!!!
        mHypeLoading = view.findViewById(R.id.hype_loading);
        mHypeRelease = view.findViewById(R.id.hype);
        mHypeCountTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.hype_count);
        mHypeCountTxt.setText("0 hypes");
        // Release actions icons
        mStarIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.star_icon);
        mHeartIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_icon);
        mNoteIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.note_icon);
        mAlarmIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_icon);
        // Default colors [hype]
        mStarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
        mHeartIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
        mNoteIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_note);
        mAlarmIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_notification);
        // Init likes (hypes) and puts color to yellow if liked
        // if game has't been released yet or has been released for a week
        if (mRelease.getDate() >= mTodayTimeMillis - 604800000) {
            initHypes(mRelease.getId());
            mHypeRelease.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mHypeRelease.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // Social actions, favorite, alarm, note, etc.
        initReleaseActions();
        // Countdown
        initCountdown(mRelease);
        // Platforms
        initPlatforms(mRelease);
        // The release date
        mHeaderReleaseDate.setText(mDateFormatterGMT.format(mRelease.getDate()));
        // Expandable TextView
        mReadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (mTextSummary.isExpanded()) {
                    mTextSummary.collapse();
                    mReadMore.setText("Read more");
                } else {
                    mTextSummary.expand();
                    mReadMore.setText("Collapse");
                }
            }
        });
        // Like [hype up] game
        mHypeRelease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    onStarClicked(mRelease, mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SignInActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadHypeLayout() {
        if (mHypeLoading.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mHypeLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHypeCountTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mStarIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mHypeLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mHypeCountTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mStarIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void initReleaseActions() {
        // User saved release actions
        if (mDatabaseHelper.favoriteExists(mRelease)) {
            mHeartIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red);
            mAddNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // If game already out, can't have alarms
            if (mRelease.getDate() >= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) {
                mEditAlarms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mEditAlarms.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            mAddNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mEditAlarms.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (mDatabaseHelper.alarmExists(mRelease)) {
            mAlarmIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_notification_blue);
        }

        if (mDatabaseHelper.noteExists(mRelease)) {
            mNoteIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_note_red);
            mNoteTxt.setText("Edit note");
        }

        mAddToFavorite.setOnClickListener(new FavoriteOnClickListener(getContext(), mRelease, mAlarmIcon, mHeartIcon, mNoteIcon,
                                                                        mAddNote, mEditAlarms));

        mAddNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddNoteFragment addNoteFragment = new AddNoteFragment();
                addNoteFragment.setDatabaseHelper(mDatabaseHelper);
                addNoteFragment.setRelease(mRelease);
                addNoteFragment.setIcon(mNoteIcon);
                addNoteFragment.setNoteTxt(mNoteTxt);
                addNoteFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), addNoteFragment.getTag());
            }
        });

        mEditAlarms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditAlarmsFragment editAlarmsFragment = new EditAlarmsFragment();
                editAlarmsFragment.setDatabaseHelper(mDatabaseHelper);
                editAlarmsFragment.setRelease(mRelease);
                editAlarmsFragment.setIcon(mAlarmIcon);
                editAlarmsFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), editAlarmsFragment.getTag());
            }
        });

        mShareRelease.setOnClickListener(new ShareOnClickListener(getContext(), mRelease, mAPISearchedGame));
    }

    public void initPlatforms(Release release) {
        List<Integer> platforms = release.getPlatforms();
        if (platforms != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i++) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 18, 0);
                TextView current = new TextView(getActivity());
                current.setId(i + 1);
                current.setLayoutParams(params);
                current.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                current.setTextSize(14);
                current.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                current.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.color_text));
                switch (platforms.get(i)) {
                    case 6:
                        current.setText("Win");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_pc);
                        break;
                    case 49:
                        current.setText("Xbox One");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_xboxone);
                        break;
                    case 48:
                        current.setText("PS4");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_ps4);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        current.setText("PS3");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_ps3);
                        break;
                    case 46:
                        current.setText("PS Vita");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_psvita);
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        current.setText("Xbox 360");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_xbox360);
                        break;
                    case 130:
                        current.setText("Nintendo Switch");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_switch);
                        break;
                    case 41:
                        current.setText("Wii U");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_wiiu);
                        break;
                    case 37:
                        current.setText("3DS");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_3ds);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        current.setText("Linux");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_linux);
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        current.setText("Mac");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_mac);
                        break;
                    case 34:
                        current.setText("Android");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_android);
                        break;
                    case 39:
                        current.setText("IOS");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_ios);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        current.setText("Wii");
                        current.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_wii);
                        break;
                }
                // if (i == 7; change to platform_2)
                if (i < 7) {
                    mPlatformsLayout.addView(current);
                } else {
                    mPlatformsLayoutExtra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mPlatformsLayoutExtra.addView(current);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initCountdown(Release release) {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332398/android-countdown-based-on-gmt-utc-and-not-the-users-timezone
        // Set the release date in millis to calender set to GMT timezone (universal)
        Calendar releaseCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        releaseCalendar.setTimeInMillis(release.getDate());
        // Get the release date
        LocalDate localReleaseDate = null;

        boolean success = false;
        int dayOfMonth = releaseCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        while (!success) {
            try {
                localReleaseDate = LocalDate.of(releaseCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        releaseCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                        dayOfMonth);
                success = true;
            } catch (DateTimeException dateTimeException) {
                // Invalid date e.g 'November 31' Small fix?
                dayOfMonth -= 1;
            }
        }

        LocalTime localReleaseTime = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0); // midnight release
        // Set to the user's timezone
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localReleaseDate, localReleaseTime, zoneId);
        // Convert from a time zone to UTC. Same point on the timeline
        Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
        Duration d = Duration.between(Instant.now(), instant);

        mCountdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(d.toMillis() , 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // 1 sec = 1000 millis
                long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                long minutes = seconds / 60;
                long hours = minutes / 60;
                long days = hours / 24;
                mDaysTxt.setText(String.valueOf(days));
                mHoursText.setText(String.valueOf(hours % 24));
                mMinutesText.setText(String.valueOf(minutes % 60));
                mSecondsText.setText(String.valueOf(seconds % 60));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mHeaderReleasesTitle.setText("Released on");
                mOutNowTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCountdownLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Games already out, can't have alarms, but they can still be hyped for a week after release
                mEditAlarms.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        };
        mCountdownTimer.start();

        long updatedAt = release.getUpdatedAt();
        if (updatedAt != 0) {
            mTxtLastUpdatedOnRelease.setText("Release date last updated on " + mDateFormatterGMT.format(updatedAt));
        }
    }

    private void setGameInfo(Game game) {
        // Stop/hide all ongoing progress bars (loading)
        mSummaryLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSocialLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mReleaseTableLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loadHypeLayout();

        // The category
        String category = game.getCategory();
        if (category != null) {
            mCategoryText.setText(game.getCategory());
        }

        String summary = game.getSummary();
        if (summary != null) {
            mTextSummary.setText(summary);
        } else {
            mTextSummary.setText("No summary available");
            mReadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        List<Website> websites = game.getWebsites();
        if (websites != null) {
            mWebsitesAdapter.setData(websites);
        } else {
            mWebsitesList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mNoWebsitesTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Organizing Table Release dates
        List<ReleaseDate> releaseDates = game.getReleaseDates();
        if (releaseDates != null) {
            // Creating the Hash map / Every region that exists will have a list of release dates
            mRegionsReleaseHashMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (ReleaseDate releaseDate : releaseDates) {
                String region = releaseDate.getRegionName();
                // Doesn't contain region
                if (!mRegionsReleaseHashMap.containsKey(region)) {
                    mRegionsReleaseHashMap.put(region, new ArrayList<ReleaseDate>());
                }
                mRegionsReleaseHashMap.get(region).add(releaseDate);
            }
            // Setting first the spinner, then the data
            if (!mRegionsReleaseHashMap.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> regions = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String region : mRegionsReleaseHashMap.keySet()) {
                    if (!regions.contains(region)) { regions.add(region); }
                }
                Collections.sort(regions); // By alpha order
                // Spinner takes an ArrayAdapter as adapter
                ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, regions);
                spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpinnerRegions.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                /*
                I removed this
                // First spinner item is always the user's region
                String defaultRegion = ((GamePageActivity) getActivity()).mRegion;
                if (regions.contains(defaultRegion)) {
                    mSpinnerRegions.setSelection(spinnerAdapter.getPosition(defaultRegion));
                } else if (regions.contains("Worldwide")) {
                    mSpinnerRegions.setSelection(spinnerAdapter.getPosition("Worldwide"));
                } */
                // Spinner listener [called on selected and on shown]
                mSpinnerRegions.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        initReleaseDatesTable(mRegionsReleaseHashMap.get(mSpinnerRegions.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            mNoReleaseDatesTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mTableReleaseDates.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        long updatedAt = game.getUpdatedAt();
        if (updatedAt != 0) {
            mTxtLastUpdatedOnGame.setText("Game data last updated on " + mDateFormatterGMT.format(updatedAt));
        }
    }

    public void initReleaseDatesTable(List<ReleaseDate> releaseDates) {
        mTableReleaseDates.removeAllViews();
        TableRow tblRowHeader = new TableRow(getContext());
        TextView txtPlatform = new TextView(getContext());
        txtPlatform.setTextSize(16);
        txtPlatform.setText("Platform");
        tblRowHeader.addView(txtPlatform);

        TextView txtReleaseDate = new TextView(getContext());
        txtReleaseDate.setTextSize(16);
        txtReleaseDate.setText("Release Date");
        tblRowHeader.addView(txtReleaseDate);

        TextView txtCountdown = new TextView(getContext());
        txtCountdown.setTextSize(16);
        txtCountdown.setText("Days left");
        tblRowHeader.addView(txtCountdown);

        mTableReleaseDates.addView(tblRowHeader);
        // Creating rows
        // One row: platform, release date and pre-order
        for (int i = 0; i < releaseDates.size(); i++) {
            TableRow tblRowData = new TableRow(getContext());

            TextView textPlatformData = new TextView(getContext());
            String platform = releaseDates.get(i).getPlatformName();
            // Gaming Reminder doesn't support/recognize this platform ;)
            if (!platform.isEmpty()) {
                textPlatformData.setTextSize(16);
                textPlatformData.setText(platform);
                tblRowData.addView(textPlatformData);

                TextView textReleaseDateData = new TextView(getContext());
                textReleaseDateData.setTextSize(16);
                long releaseTimeMillis = releaseDates.get(i).getDate();
                textReleaseDateData.setText(mDateFormatterGMT.format(releaseTimeMillis));
                tblRowData.addView(textReleaseDateData);

                TextView textCountdownData = new TextView(getContext());
                textCountdownData.setTextSize(16);
                long daysLeft = AppUtil.daysBetween(releaseTimeMillis);
                if (daysLeft <= 0) {
                    textCountdownData.setText("Now Out");
                } else {
                    textCountdownData.setText(daysLeft + " days");
                }
                tblRowData.addView(textCountdownData);
                mTableReleaseDates.addView(tblRowData);
            }
        }
    }

    // Shows the number of likes in our respective likes count view
    private void initHypes(final long releaseId) {
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Loading likes...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DatabaseReference likeRef = mLikesRef.child(mRegion);
        likeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(releaseId)).exists()) {
                    long starCount = dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(releaseId)).child("starCount").getValue(Long.class);
                    mHypeCountTxt.setText(starCount + " hypes");
                    // Now check if current logged in user hyped it (the release) up
                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                        // the stars node is only used to check if the current user hyped up the current game
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(releaseId)).child("stars").hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                            mStarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_yellow);
                        } else {
                            mStarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
                        }
                    }
                } // else : no votes yet for this release
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }

    private void onStarClicked(final Release release, final String uid) {
        final DatabaseReference postRef = mLikesRef.child(mRegion).child(String.valueOf(release.getId()));
        postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
                if (p == null) {
                    // When p is null this means, the release object [no node exists] hasn't been added to likes
                    p = new Post();
                    p.setStarCount(1);
                    p.setRelease(release);
                    p.setDate(release.getDate());
                    p.getStars().put(uid, true);
                    mutableData.setValue(p);
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                if (p.getStars().containsKey(uid)) {
                    // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                    p.setStarCount(p.getStarCount() - 1);
                    if (p.getStarCount() == 0) {
                        // Delete the node
                        postRef.removeValue();
                    }
                    // remove the entire key
                    p.getStars().remove(uid);
                } else {
                    // Star the post and add self to stars
                    p.setStarCount(p.getStarCount() + 1);
                    // Update the date [flawed, some release dates saved in likes can have a different release date]
                    // Update the release each time the user puts a star
                    p.setRelease(release);
                    p.getStars().put(uid, true);
                }

                // Set value and report transaction success
                mutableData.setValue(p);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                   DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Transaction completed
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataLoaded(Game game) {
        mCategoryText.setText("but");
        setGameInfo(game);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set them?  YOu haven't posted anywhere near enough code for us to help you.

Comment: Of course I did, everything works perfectly, until background and come back to app

Comment: Can you add the Fragment's code? It can have to do with where you declared the UI views, or not saving some state in onPause().

Comment: @Juan okay np!!

Answer (score 0):

When you app is put in the background and brought back, it can kill the fragment and recreated it. If you method `setGameInfo` is being called with nulls its because the method is being called between when the Fragment is recreated and when its `onViewCreated` (where you set up the view references) is called.

From your code, I have to guess there is something happening in the owning Activity that invokes the fragment's `onDataLoaded` method while the fragment is still be initialized.

Use your debugger to put a breakpoint at this method and in `onViewCreated` to see which is being called first and why.

Comment: Yes I observe a live data object in my MainActivity the observe method calls onDataLoaded

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem, or most part of it at least is where you are initializing the views.

As a rule of thumb, anything that needs to be created for the `Fragment` which is not a View should be declared in `onCreate()`, and anything with a `findViewById()` should go in `onCreateView()`, not `onViewCreated()`.

For example, I would move this part to onCreate():

```
    String dateFormat = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.KEY_PREF_DATE_FORMAT,      getString(R.string.default_date_format));
    mDateFormatterGMT = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    mDateFormatterGMT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    mTodayTimeMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    mAlarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
```

Also put here the creation of the adapter and the database helper:

```
mWebsitesAdapter = new WebsitesAdapter(getContext());
```

Other candidates for onCreate() are:

```
    String region = SharedPrefManager.read(SharedPrefManager.KEY_PREF_REGION, "north_america");
    mRegion = SharedPrefManager.getRegionToFilter(region);
    // Release social actions
    // The RELEASE DATA OBJECT
    mRelease = ((GamePageActivity)getActivity()).getRelease();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                // When the user signs in in this page [refresh]
               initHypes(mRelease.getId());
            }
        }
    };
```

And most if not all you have in `onViewCreated()` to `onCreateView()`

I didn't run your code and it is quite long, so there may be exceptions to this in what you have done, but onViewCreated() should remian practically empty after the refactoring.

Note: I think the databasehelper is set twice, after moving it ot onCreate() you shouldn't need to repeat the initialization somewhere else.